# Unable to change default font in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to change the default font in my app. But its not working. These are steps I have taken:

1) Created class **TypefaceUtil.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {

public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CustomFontException", "Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
    }
  }
}
```

2) In a class extending **Application**:

```
public void onCreate() {

     super.onCreate();
     TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "MONOSPACE", "fonts/varelaround_regular.ttf");
 }
```

3)  In **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
 </style>
```

Still its not working. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Weird, I used the same code and it was working fine for me. Only difference is that I used `serif` instead of `monospace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced this problem once. I am not very sure why it works, but you can try the following :
Instead of "monospace", try each of these:
DEFAULT, SANS_SERIF, SERIF. It might not work for all textviews, like those in ListView or recyclerView (weird, right?). But in those cases, I set the typeface programatically from the adapter. 
Sorry for unable to explain the reason.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, i highly recommend you to use `Calligraphy`, https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy, an awesome lib, really strait-forward to change the default font with it, and has many other useful functionalities.

Everything you need to set this up should be in the Readme.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not define your custom TextView and assign any font to it.**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.exmple.util.Utility;

public class CustomFontEditText extends EditText {

    private Context mContext;

    private String ttfName;

    String TAG = getClass().getName();

    public CustomFontEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public CustomFontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.mContext = context;

        // Typeface.createFromAsset doesn't work in the layout editor.
        // Skipping...
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
            this.ttfName = attrs.getAttributeValue(Utility.ATTRIBUTE_SCHEMA,
                    Utility.ATTRIBUTE_TTF_KEY);

            if (null != ttfName)
                init();
        }

    }

    public CustomFontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface font = Utility.getFonts(mContext, ttfName);
        if (null != font)
            setTypeface(font);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {

        super.setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Load and store font from asset in a hash map in your Utility class so that you can reuse font later. Imagine loading font each time new View get loaded .. OOM ..!!!

```
private static Map<String, Typeface> TYPEFACE = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
public static Typeface getFonts(Context context, String fontName) {
    Typeface typeface = TYPEFACE.get(fontName);
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
        TYPEFACE.put(fontName, typeface);
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

Add ttf attribute to set font from xml

```
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_TTF_KEY = "ttf_name";

public static final String ATTRIBUTE_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.exmaple.ui.customfont";
```

and now use in your layout file

```
 <com.example.ui.customviews.CustomFontEditText
            xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.exmaple.ui.customfont"
            android:id="@+id/edt_pay_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashed_white"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            font:ttf_name="FedraSansStd-Light.otf" >

            <requestFocus />
        </com.example.ui.customviews.CustomFontEditText>
```

You can do the same for Button,TextView etc.